# Where can I find this article by I. Ruzsa?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, additive-combinatorics, sumset

Title says it all. Have tried googling and my college library, but no success so far.

I. Ruzsa, On the cardinality of $A + A$ and $A − A$. In *Combinatorics (Keszthely, 1976), Coll. Math. Soc. Bolyai* **18**, Akadémiai Kaidó (1979), 933–938

Comment: This is [MR0519317](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=519317), but unfortunately it has no link to the article. It seems to be part of a book: https://books.google.com/books?id=Ykw_AQAAIAAJ&q=Ruzsa,+%22On+the+cardinality+of%22&dq=Ruzsa,+%22On+the+cardinality+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin6rer2JLcAhWRy1MKHSUrAYYQ6AEITjAH

Comment: Google Books links to WorldCat, where you can find libraries which have the conference proceedings: http://www.worldcat.org/title/combinatorics/oclc/4809025

Comment: I finally managed to find it in the university library with the information you provided - thanks a lot!